# CoreData Fault, when i am trying to get data from NSSet for current user, I am getting following error."

Tags: ios, core-data

CoreData Fault, when I am trying to get data from NSSet for current user,  `<_currentUser.UserAddresses.allObjects[indexPath.row]);>`
I am getting the following error:

```
 "<Address: 0x7fd66a54a4c0> (entity: Address; id: 0x7fd66a5a6f10 <x-coredata://0EF4F398-8357-4A52-9BC3-2C6E6B9A5014/Address/p1> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2014-11-27 11:45:27.829 Icare[2657:39674] Row Value 0
2014-11-27 11:46:43.381 Icare [2657:39674] Array Value <Address: 0x7fd66a54a4c0> (entity: Address; id: 0x7fd66a5a6f10 <x-coredata://0EF4F398-8357-4A52-9BC3-2C6E6B9A5014/Address/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error.  A fault is where the data associated with an object has not yet been retrieved from the database.  See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) for a fuller explanation.  If you access any of the attributes of that object, CoreData will automatically "fire" the fault, retrieving the relevant data from the database.

Comment: Please give me proper solution and steps to solve this issue.

Comment: It's not an issue. It's a normal behavior of Core Data. It says "fault", but in Core Data's terminology it means "an object which has not loaded its properties from the persistent store into memory (RAM) yet". It's kind of a "lazy loading" pattern.

Comment: There is no issue - it is entirely as expected.  You don't need to do anything about it.  Please update your post with more info if you  think there is still a problem.